# Вычислить значение функции на заданном интервале в Python

Tags: python, функции, математика, циклы

Стоит задача написать программу на языке Python для вычисления 8-ми значений функции y =    3.14 * (x^3 - 6x^2)^1/3 на заданном интервале x от -3 до 8. Контрольные значения: x = 3.0; y = -9.4.

Подскажите решение с объяснением, если можно :)

Comment: Мне нравится как всё здесь работает) Если вопрос выглядит как "решите мне пожалуйста", но при этом он легкий - быстро находятся желающие. Но если что-то посложнее, то вопрос сразу минусуется, автору пишут, мол, покажи сначала что ты сам пробовал сделать. Почему так?

Comment: @whizz169 на что только люди ради рейтинга не пойдут...

Comment: @whizz169 ну не все такие, я минусую и вопрос и ответ(если он не написан так чтобы автор вопроса не мог понять решение, ответы достойные попасть в "код гольф" я наоборот плюсую в таких вопросах)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков В чем проблема помочь человеку который только начал разбираться с программированием предоставив код тривиальной задачи с объяснениями? Почти всегда проблема у человека в том, что вообще непонятно откуда начать, что написать чтобы хоть что-то запустилось, и такие ответы помогают этот рубеж преодолеть.

Comment: @StanislavTsepa помочь человеку который **начал** или **начинает** разбираться - никакой проблемы, а вот **решить задачу** за человека - не поможет ему разобраться =) Начинать "пробовать" свои силы нужно как минимум после прочтения книги(или вводных статей), после которых вопрос будет звучать совершенно иначе(при естественно усвоении материала). Помогать по вопросам из топика - нет смысла, в вопросе нет(не видно) попыток решить задачу самостоятельно.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков утверждение что "Начинать "пробовать" свои силы нужно как минимум после прочтения книги(или вводных статей)" это сильное преувеличение. По вашему те кто не выполнил эти "минимальные" требования недостойны заниматься программированием?) Есть и другие возможности, например человек занимается в кружке или школе. Часто там методика не особо отточена и в итоге человек остается один на один с домашним заданием к которому не знает как подступиться.

Comment: @StanislavTsepa по моему мнению - человек который не предпринял **самостоятельной** попытки решить проблему - не достоин помощи. Да это жестоко, зато правда.
Теперь по второй части вашего сообщения, вы можете посмотреть все мои комментарии и ответы, и увидеть что зачастую вопросы(подобные), в которых автор выказывает желание разобраться - получают вполне вменяемые комментарии, с них убирается мой минус, и иногда даже получают решение в виде готового кода(а не объяснений как его написать).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала реализуем функцию которая для данного `x` будет вычислять `y` (используется python3). Вычислить кубический корень средствами языка не такая простая задача -- надо учитывать знак, поэтому воспользуемся функцией [`cbrt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cbrt.html) из библиотеки `numpy`

```py
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return 3.14 * np.cbrt(x ** 3 - 6 * x ** 2)
```

Проверим что она работает:

```py
>>> f(3)
-9.420000000000002
```

Далее надо вычислить значения функции в 8 точках от -3 до 8, чтобы не углубляться выберем точки вручную:

```py
for x in (-3, -1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8):
    y = f(x)
    print(x, y)

# -3 -13.585990952295788
# -1 -6.006603913905303
# 0 0.0
# 1 -5.369324472564828
# 2 -7.912304193339805
# 4 -9.968878606360294
# 6 0.0
# 8 15.82460838667961
```

Если важно чтобы точки шли равномерно от -3 до 8 то можно использовать функцию `np.linspace`

```py
>>> np.linspace(-3, 8, 8)
array([-3.        , -1.42857143,  0.14285714,  1.71428571,  3.28571429,
        4.85714286,  6.42857143,  8.        ])
```

```py
for x in np.linspace(-3, 8, 8):
    y = f(x)
    print(x, y)

# -3.0 -13.585990952295788
# -1.4285714285714286 -7.7714022593441
# 0.1428571428571428 -1.5467717335431101
# 1.7142857142857144 -7.30566112809258
# 3.2857142857142856 -9.680579719497558
# 4.857142857142857 -9.415590204613062
# 6.428571428571429 8.184906114043065
# 8.0 15.82460838667961
```

Comment: Воистину, зачем просто, если можно сложно? :)

Answer (score -1):

```
def f(x):
    x = x*x*(x-6)
    if x < 0 : sign = -1
    else: sign = 1
    x = x*sign
    return sign*3.14*x**(1/3)


for i in range(8):
    print (f(-3+i*11/7))

print(f(3))
```